How to update apps without logging into a Google account for multiple tablets?
We are a company that sets up multiple tablets for our customers with the same Google account. Our customers are complaining that they are constantly being logged out and have to log in again to update our apps.
Is there any way we can have our customers update our apps without having to constantly log into the Google account? I saw there is Aurora Store, but I don't want to risk losing our Google Play Console privileges if Google finds out our customers are downloading from there.
What is the best approach here?

Google accounts are limited regarding the number of devices you can register in it. Not sure about the exact number but it was below10. On your question I simply don't understand why you use this approach. May be there are better ways to achieve what you need but your description is too short to understand the scenario.

What you're looking for is a Mobile Device Management solution which allows you to remotely manage enterprise devices - https://www.android.com/enterprise/management/
There are service providers like InTune, Google Workspace and others that support that. They allow remote deployment of application updates among other things required for companies to manage their dedicated devices.
